# Using CSS ::before tag to display list item index on multiple levels

Tags: css

I'm trying to write the css styles for a two level ordered list, and using the `::before` to display the index of the listitem. Everything works fine, except the index of the parent `li` is somehow displayed in the content of the `li` as well.

Heres the fiddle project with the problem:
[jsfiddle.net/h3nt9bfw/](http://jsfiddle.net/h3nt9bfw/)

In the `li` with index 8 there is a 8 at the top right of the `li` content, and I'd like to remove it, but cant seem to make the css right. Please someone advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get rid of it using this-

```
ol.subQuestions.sortableQuestionLists.ui-sortable.ui-droppable:before {
    content: ""!important;
}
```

you could simplify the selector but thats the basic idea here